# Is it possible to create random numbers using (time-dependent) functions or functionals?

Tags: functions, random

I saw a tv program asking for the name of a mathematician. The answer was von Neumann. It was said that he tried to create random numbers, but these numbers showed periodic behavior. After a while, the same row of numbers came back again and again.
Now if you use mathematics only, is it possible to create random numbers? Is it possible to create a function that has as its values random numbers? Functions that depend on time or maybe functional? Or will they cease to be a function or a functional if that could be done?

Comment: A function is by definition deterministic: it always maps a given input to the same output. As far as I know there's no algorithmic way to produce genuinely random numbers. Modern computer CPUs have [hardware random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator), which are driven by some (presumably) genuinely random process such as thermal noise.

Comment: I believe you are talking about von Neumann's middle square method. It generates pseudo-random numbers, not truly random. Atmospheric noise is often said to be a truly random process, and is used as such, for generating random numbers.

Comment: @Bungo A function is indeed deterministic. But why should it be impossible to create one that determines randomness. For example, one that gives, for every two integers, a truly random number? Pick one and you will get 22, pick two and you will get 71, pick 3 and you will get 1117, etc. The numbers are indeed determined by the function, but why are they necessarily non-random if they are determined?

Comment: So, $f(1) = 22, f(2) = 71, f(3) = 1117$, etc.? And $22$, $71$, and $1117$ are numbers that you've somehow chosen randomly? But how did you choose them randomly? By what algorithm?

Comment: There are very good algorithms creating pseudorandom sequences , but of course they do never produce a truely random sequence. To achieve this, we must involve physical processes, this is already be done in cases we need truely randomness.

Comment: Side note: in order to even define "random numbers", you need to define the allowable set of random numbers and a probability distribution on this set. One thing worth noting, since it's not clear what you're proposing in your example, is that there's no way to choose randomly from $\mathbb N$ (the set of all positive integers) with equal probability (uniformly).

Comment: @Bungo Can't truly random processes, like thermal noise, be represented as a function of space and time?

Comment: No, we can model random processes mathematically by defining a probability distribution on a set of sample functions, but ultimately you're facing the same limitation: the mathematical theory of probability doesn't specify how to actually generate random numbers from a probability distribution. It assumes there's some underlying random behavior that is driving the generation. For example, to generate truly random real numbers in the interval $[0,1]$, you could flip a coin infinitely many times and express the result as a binary decimal fraction. But coin flipping is not an algorithm!

Comment: @Bungo What is the algorithm by which I've chosen the numbers? Why can't I choose them randomly? Can't I just point my finger at a collection of numbers and, depending on the position of my finger, choose one of them? How can I be sure that my pointing is truly random? Why shouldn't it? Isn't this the way balls for the lotto games are chosen? The problem is how to mimic this in a functional way. You can pick different values of x (and t, time) of a function and assign random numbers to them (like a lotto machine) Why can't there exist a function that does the same?

Comment: And coin flipping isn't *really* random, either. In principle the outcome can be completely determined by elementary physics if modeled with sufficient accuracy.

Comment: @Bungo Yes indeed. It depends on the initial values. But how can you make these random? Does randomness exist at all in this way? In quantum mechanics it exists. Though even there hidden variables can do the job.

Comment: I don't know much about physics, but I'm not sure if it's actually known whether there's anything truly random in the universe. I believe some aspects of quantum mechanics are consistent with true randomness, but quantum mechanics is only a model that is consistent with observed behavior, not necessarily an explanation of what's "really" happening.

Comment: @Bungo A function always maps the input to the same output. But what if we make the input depend on time?